# Filtering a column in data frame which contains a list

Tags: python, regex, dataframe, filter

I have a data frame in which one of the column contains list. I am trying to filter this column using regex but all I am getting is empty data frame.

```
                            Source                    Length
0              [the sub-study process is over., EEE]       2
1  [Optional Pharma (DNA Research), Sub-Study inf...       2
2       [Sub-study ............................  41]       1
```

I am trying to filter rows whose "Source Column" contains "(.*?)" at the end of the string in the list (example: **1  [Optional Pharma (DNA Research), Sub-Study inf...       2:** this row has (DNA Research) at the end of the first value in the list) using the below code.

```
print(file_df.filter( regex=r'\(.*?\)\Z',axis=0))
```

Output is

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [ Source, Length]
Index: []
```

Then I tried this,

```
print(file_df[file_df.Source.str.match('\(.*?\)\Z')])
```

for which I got

```
KeyError: '[nan  nan] not in index'
```

Can someone point me where I am going wrong with the code.

Adding my code:

```
def sentence_process(file_df):
  print(file_df.loc[file_df['Source'].str.contains(r'^[^,]*\([^()]*\)',regex= True)])
```

Comment: Try `r'^[^,]*\([^()]*\)'`. The `\Z` pattern matches the very end of string in Python `re`.

Comment: So, have you  tried `file_df['Source'].str.contains(r'^[^,]*\([^()]*\)')`? Or something like that?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : I tried your method file_df['Source'].str.contains(r'^[^,]*\([^()]*\)')  but I am getting NAN as output..

Comment: However that works fine if I try it with a single string but when i try it with a dataframe, I am getting NAN values

Comment: Try `file_df[file_df['Source'].str.contains(r'^[^,]*\([^()]*\)')]`

Comment: Tried the above method : got this result KeyError: 'None of [0   NaN\n1   NaN\n2   NaN\nName: Source, dtype: float64] are in the [index]' . I have added 2 more columns for workaround thats y the extra columns in the error msg but I still have "Source" Column untouched.

Comment: Wait, are there lists inside `Source` column? Could you please provide a reproducible code snippet?

Comment: Yes, I have lists in he source column and there is nothing much of a code. Because I am trying this as separate module and this is my starting point.

Comment: I want to know whether it is possible to file a column of lists? Else I will think of a different approach

Comment: If you help me repro the issue, I can help better. See [here, it works with lists](http://rextester.com/GKVL37183), but I might have failed to repro your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import re

for Index, Row in DF.iterrows():
    if any(re.findall('\(.+\)$', Item) for Item in file_df['Source'][Index]):
        print (Row)
```

You'll get the output:

```
Source    [Optional Pharma (DNA Research), Sub-Study inf]
Length                                                  2
Name: 1, dtype: object
```